# intValue always return 0

Tags: objective-c, casting

That's code:

```
NSLog(@"value  = %@",[currentPatient kids_val]);
NSLog(@"value  = %d",[[currentPatient kids_val] intValue]);
```

And this is console:

```
2012-07-23 21:43:52.665 Sample[24491:207] value  = 
    14
2012-07-23 21:43:52.665 Sample[24491:207] value  = 0
```

I need intValue. But it returns 0. I think there is a '/r' problem.

Comment: Going to need some more information - what type is returned by `[currentPatient kids_val]`? What value do you expect it to have?

Comment: Is kids_val NSNumber, NSValue, or id?

Comment: Assuming the target is parsing a string, I think you're right -- there's a stray leading newline. You could trim it, but probably better to work out why it's getting there in the first place.

Comment: i solved it with using 'stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]' Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is problem of '/r', `intValue` returns 0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number.